# How to prove that reaction is possible

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I have been given task to write possible reaction equations, determine oxidizer, reducer, write corresponding electron-equations and calculate electromotive force (I do not know if that is what you call it in English) of reactions:

1. Iron reaction with diluted sulfuric acid
2. Aluminium reaction with solution of sodium hydroxide

Could you be so kind and help me with this task?

Comment: This looks like it might be homework. We don't directly answer homework questions (certainly if no effort has been attempted). Have you tried searching the web with the reagents?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. You were lucky to receive an answer this time, but please adhere to this practice in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ionic equation for this reaction is:

$\ce{Fe + 2H+ ~(+\;SO4^2- ) -> Fe^2+ + H2 ~(+\;SO4^2- )}$

As two half-reactions, it is seen that the iron is oxidized:

$\ce{Fe -> Fe^2+ + 2e- }$

The reductant (iron) transfers electrons to hydrogen, and is thus itself oxidized.

And the hydrogen is reduced:

$\ce{2H+ + 2e- -> H2}$

The oxidant (hydrogen) removes electrons from iron, and is thus itself reduced.

To calculate the reduction potential you have to solve the following equation:

$\Delta E = E_\text{acceptor} - E_\text{donor} = E_{\ce{2H+/H2}}- E_{\ce{Fe/Fe^2+}}$

$\Delta E = 0\ \mathrm{V} - (-0.41\ \mathrm{V}) = 0.41\ \mathrm{V}$

The reactions runs voluntarily if $\Delta E > 0$.

You can do the same for b).